# Perfect number in java using methods for homework

Tags: java, methods, perfect-numbers

I had a to write a homework for class and got stuck with it, can't figure out how to make it set up correctly like it is supposed to. I appreciate any help I get thank you. This is the assignment:

> An integer number is said to be a perfect number if its factors,
>   including 1 (but not the numbers itself), sum to the number. For
>   example,6 is a perfect number, because 6=1+2+3. Write method Perfect
>   that determines whether number is a perfect number. Use this method in
>   an application that determines and displays all the perfect numbers
>   between 2 and 1000. Display the factors of each perfect number to
>   confirm that the number is indeed perfect.

Output:

```
6 is perfect.
Factors:1 2 3
28 is perfect.
Factors: 1 2 4 7 14
496 is perfect.
Factors: 1 2 4 8 16 31 62 124 248
```

and here is the code I got stuck with:

```
public class Homework4 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        for(int num=2;num<=1000;num++)
        {
            if(perfect(num))
            {
                System.out.println(num + " is perfect.");
                System.out.printf("Factors: ",perfect(num));

            }

        }
    }
        public static Boolean perfect(int num)
        {
            int sum = 0;

            for(int i=1;i<num;i++)
            {
                if (num % i == 0)
                {
                    sum+=i;
                }
            }
            if(num==sum)
            {
            for(int i=1;i<num;i++)
            {
                if (num % i == 0)
                {
                    System.out.print(i+" ");
                }
            }


            }
            return sum==num;
        }

}
```

run:

```
1 2 3 6 is perfect.
1 2 3 Factors: 1 2 4 7 14 28 is perfect.
1 2 4 7 14 Factors: 1 2 4 8 16 31 62 124 248 496 is perfect.
1 2 4 8 16 31 62 124 248 Factors: BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Comment: Except the "Factors" which isn't shown at the expected place I guess

Comment: If that's the problem, it is due to the fact that you call perfect(num) in the if before so it outputs factors before the perfect number, and then I doubt the use of printf(a,b)

Comment: yes that is the problem. So how would i fix the order of the program to get it to be like the output i showed?

Comment: Did you manage to get correct output in the end?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, but I never managed to get the correct output but my professor let the program slide since I got most it right.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways you could fix this.

- You could break your `perfect` method into two separate methods - one that checks whether the number is perfect, and one that prints its factors.  Call the first one when you're checking - and if it returns true, then call the second one.

Or

- You could move the line that prints `... is perfect` into the method itself.  Then remove the entire `if` block from `main`.

Comment: When I remove the if block from main I result in an error.

Comment: And if you'll tell us WHAT the error is, someone might be able to help you.  You'll still need a call to `perfect(num)` inside the `for` loop, of course, but I think that should go without saying.

Comment: If you meant removing if(perfect(num)), id result in error because it wouldn't check for if num was true. I'm sorry if im not coming back with good replies with this.

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this :

```
public class Homework4 {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    for(int num=2;num<=1000;num++)
    {
        if(perfect(num))
        {
            System.out.println(num + " is perfect.");
            System.out.printf("Factors: ");


            for(int i=1;i<num;i++)
            {
                if (num % i == 0)
                {
                     System.out.print(i+" ");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
public static Boolean perfect(int num)
{
    int sum = 0;

    for(int i=1;i<num;i++)
    {
        if (num % i == 0)
        {
            sum+=i;
        }
    }
    return sum==num;
}
}
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't check if working or not, but order seems better like this. "perfect" method doesn't need to output anything, it's goal is only to check if the number is perfect

Comment: run:
6 is perfect.
Factors: 1 2 3 28 is perfect.
Factors: 1 2 4 7 14 496 is perfect.
Factors: 1 2 4 8 16 31 62 124 248 BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
is what I get with yours. Still doesn't get the output right but seems closer thanks for the help so far!

Comment: You just need to add line return no?

Answer (score -2):

Try this

```
public class Homework4 {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    for(int num=2;num<=1000;num++)
    {
        if(perfect(num))
        {
            System.out.println(num + " is perfect.");
            System.out.printf("Factors: ");


            for(int i=1;i<num;i++)
            {
                if (num % i == 0)
                {
                     System.out.print(i+" ");
                }
            }
            System.out.print("\n"); // add this line to your code

        }
    }
}
public static Boolean perfect(int num)
{
    int sum = 0;

    for(int i=1;i<num;i++)
    {
        if (num % i == 0)
        {
            sum+=i;
        }
    }
    return sum==num;
}
}
```

Answer (score -3):

```java
public class Homework4 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        prime();
    }//end main

     public static void prime(){
                int sum=0;
                for(int i=1;i<=1000;i++){
                    
                    for(int k=2;k<i;k++){
                        
                        if(i%k==0){
                          sum+=i/k;
                        }//end if
                        
                        if(sum+1==i && k==i-1){
                              System.out.println(i);
                              
                        }//end if
                                  
                        
                        
                    }//end inner for

                    sum=0;

                }//end outer for
                
            }//end prime
    
    
}//end class
```

output

> 6
>
> 28
>
> 496